# How is it possible to select the value as array using sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, select

While selecting the values in mysql from a table,
for example groups g, which has the columns g.id, g.name

there is another table called group_members

I need to fetch all the groups with all the members

So the sql will return the result as

```
1. group_id : 1, group_name : john, members_ids : [12,14]
2. group_id : 2  group_name : jill, members_ids : [12,13,14,15]



SELECT g.id as group_id, 
g.name as group_name,
ug.members_ids
FROM groups g
LEFT JOIN group_members gm on gm.user_id = [Userid]
```

GROUPS TABLE

---

```
id | name
-----------
1 | group 1
2 | group 2
```

group_members Table

---

```
id | group_id | user_id
1  | 1        | 12
2  | 1        | 14
3  | 2        | 12
4  | 2        | 13
4  | 2        | 13
```

Comment: Sample table data _and_ the expected result would be great!

Comment: mysql 5.7 
group_concat works
but JSON functons does not, I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can try to use `GROUP_CONCAT` function

```
SELECT 
    g.id as group_id, 
    g.name as group_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(gm.user_id SEPARATOR ',')  members_ids
FROM groups g
LEFT JOIN group_members gm on g.id = gm.group_id
GROUP BY 
    g.id, 
    g.name
```

or display as JSON array you can try to use `JSON_ARRAYAGG` function

```
SELECT 
    g.id as group_id, 
    g.name as group_name,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(gm.user_id)  members_ids
FROM groups g
LEFT JOIN group_members gm on g.id = gm.group_id
GROUP BY 
    g.id, 
    g.name
```

Comment: Topicstarter keep in mind that `JSON_ARRAYAGG` only works from MySQL version around 5.7.20/22  i believe

Comment: The group concat returns only one row

`SELECT 
    g.id as group_id, 
    g.name as group_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(gm.user_id SEPARATOR ',')  members_ids
FROM groups g
LEFT JOIN group_members gm on g.id = gm.group_id
GROUP BY 
    g.id, 
    g.name 

`

the below code returns all the rows, but if i select the group concat it returns only one row



`
SELECT 
    g.id as group_id, 
    g.name as group_name
FROM groups g
LEFT JOIN group_members gm on g.id = gm.group_id
GROUP BY 
    g.id, 
    g.name
`